# Button disable but not enable

Tags: asp.net

when i click btn control disable btn using javascript then btn click event call.
inside btn click event i write code which gives me report in excel/pdf format for that i use method 
ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.Excel, Response, true, "Report Name") which gives me exception so after this method 
or finally block when i write btn.enable=true; or use javascript then not executed.
exception is Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

i.e. i have to enable btn when report is generated.
as this method get executed ExportToHttpResponse() i got report
so after this method i have to enable btn control

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnExcel.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnExcel, null) + ";");
}


protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   view_report();
    try
    {
       Rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.Excel, Response, true, " Reportname");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ex = null;
    }
    finally
    {                  
       btnExcel.Enabled = true;
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "CallJSFunction", "myEnablefunction()", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the contents of the javascript `myEnablefunction()`.

Comment: function myEnablefunction(){ btnExcel.disabled=false;}

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing directly to the Response, all the asp.net structure is broke, so you cannot change the property of the control, because you already interfered in the "natural" rendering of asp.net. If there's an error in the middle of the export, the page is broken.